# Can't SSH into AWS EC2 instance after Ubuntu sudo do-release-upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

TL;DR: Can't SSH to my EC2 instance after upgrading Ubuntu.

I set up a EC2 instance with Bitnami Wordpress AMI. The image has Ubuntu 16.04 and I want Ubuntu 18.04 so I connected to the instance via SSH using PuTTY with

> ubuntu@ec2-{ip}.compute-1.amazonaws.com

and once inside I did

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

During upgrade I was prompted to choose between updating or preserving ssh_config. I chose to preserve it because I wanted to use the SSH key I had set for the instance.

I was prompted to reboot the instance which I did. After reboot the server works (I can connect to it from my browser) but I can't connect via SSH. PuTTY error message is

> Network error: Connection refused.

I did notice the ip changed after reboot and I did use the new ip when trying to connect.

Additionally: I don't know how to check the contents of ssh_config or if the SSH service is running without connecting via SSH.

Comment: Try to obtain the console log. Check if the machine has booted. Can you access any service? Is it answering to ping?

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici The site is up so it has booted. From AWS console I can get system log. I notice it tries to start SSH multiple times but fails. Here is a relevant snippet

https://pastebin.com/GSSEuVTi

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the VM and attach its disk to another new temporary VM. Then  check the logs (`journalctl -b --file=/path/to//var/log/journal/....`). Fix the syntax error in `/path/to/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Verify the sshd config with `sshd -T -f /path/to/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Detach the disk, then try to boot again the machine.

Comment: It seems an ubuntu instance will not persist the journal file. SSH is configured to log to AUTH, so /var/log/auth.log

Comment: You can create `/var/log/journal` directory to make it persistent.

Comment: True, but we're talking about an investigation after the fact, so that doesn't help.